# How to get int from float in picat?

Tags: picat

I try to to read a line as string from console (stdin) in picat and get its half:

```
main =>
  L = read_line(),
  B = L.length/2,
  S = L.slice(1,B),
  println(S).
```

crashes with `error(integer_expected(2.0),slice)`

when int used instead of B - no crash. So how to turn B into integer?

Answer (score 2):

you could use built-in function such as `floor`, `round` or `ceiling` from `math module` (more functions [here](http://picat-lang.org/download/math.pi)). So you could modify your code like this:

```
main =>
    L = read_line(),
    B = round(L.length/2),
    S = L.slice(1,B),
    println(S).
```

Answer (score 0):

Try either using `integer(..)` function to convert `L.length/2` to integer or use `to_integer()` function....should do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

type inference plays an essential role in functional evaluation. (/ /2) it's a floating point arithmetic operator, but slice/2 expects an integer. So you should instead use (// /2).

```
Picat> L=read_line(),println(L.slice(1,L.length//2)).
123456789
1234
L = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9']
yes
```